# Looking for fish theme with powerline, full path and return and carriage return after the prompt line

Tags: theme, fish

I'm looking for a theme I noticed some time ago and that I can't find again, it was a theme on fish or zsh where the prompt line (user & path) had powerline theme, the full path was displayed and after that line there was a carriage return so the typed command was done on an empty line. Could anyone refer me to that config I'd like to implement that with fish.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about oh-my-zsh's "bira" theme. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes#bira).

It could also be [amuse](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes#amuse).